# How to tell jekyll-build to skip a file that I don't want it to build?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

As part of a process of writing papers, I usually have a markdown file in my repo - these render fine as part of the jekyll-build process, although mostly I'm just interested in rendering the HTML files I have.

Recently, I changed one of those markdown files to use a Jinja2 template to avoid some repetition. Jinja2 apaprently uses some similar syntax to Liquid. So when my [template file](https://github.com/brevzin/cpp_proposals/blob/3441946af5a1c6fc39abc4082fce33de8f46a85d/3171_boost_lambda2/boost-lambda2.tpl#L314) has syntax like this:

```
{% macro make_binary_func(name, op) %}
// ... some stuff 
{% endmacro %}
```

The [jekyll-build](https://github.com/brevzin/cpp_proposals/actions/runs/8125500722/job/22208179500) breaks, complaining about:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 299): Unknown tag 'macro' in 3171_boost_lambda2/boost-lambda2.tpl
```

Which, sure - this isn't Liquid, so it's unsurprising that it complains. Liquid seems far more limited - doesn't seem to have a function/macro construct?

Is there a way for me to get jekyll-build to either ignore this file or just treat it as raw text and something not to be rendered? All I care about is that my [html file](https://github.com/brevzin/cpp_proposals/blob/3441946af5a1c6fc39abc4082fce33de8f46a85d/3171_boost_lambda2/p3171r0.html) shows up on github-pages properly.

Comment: sounds like you set up things incorrectly and it's still trying to render with liquid instead of jinja? so the title of your question is not really what you're looking for?

Comment: @mb21 OK can I get a hint as to how to set things up correctly? I didn't actually set anything up, this is whatever github-pages does by default.

Comment: huh, you wrote "I changed one of those markdown files to use a Jinja2 template" – but jekyll doesn't use jinja (which is python anyway?!) Jekyll is written in Ruby and uses Liquid, see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/

Comment: @mb21 I'm not even intentionally using jekyll! I'm using Jinja to manually render a file. I didn't need/want Jekyll to render the original markdown file, and I definitely don't want Jekyll to render the current template file.

Comment: @mb21 This file is not for jekyll. This file is for producing an html file that is for github-pages. How do I get jekyll to only care about the html file?

Comment: Huh, are you using jekyll or not?!

Comment: @mb21 I just have a repo I want to render on github-pages. All I want it to do is serve html files and a few, select markdown files. But instead jekyll attempts to render every single file in the repo - which causes problems, because I don't want it to render every single file in the repo. Does it have a way to select files or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Liquid doesn't have macros.
Maybe you're looking for Raw {% raw %} {% endraw %} ?

Comment: I'm not looking to use Liquid or Jekyll at all. I don't need this file rendered in any way. The macro I'm using works great for what I'm using it for.

Answer (score 0):

To [disable Jekyll completely on GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages):

> If you publish your site from a source branch, GitHub Pages will use Jekyll to build your site by default. If you want to use a static site generator other than Jekyll, we recommend that you write a GitHub Actions to build and publish your site instead. Otherwise, disable the Jekyll build process by creating an empty file called `.nojekyll` in the root of your publishing source

If you want only a specific file or part of a file to not be parsed as liquid template, @Nick Christiny is right that you need to wrap it inbetween `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`.